# Deduplicate forwarded emails sent to mutiple distribution groups

Tags: microsoft-office-365, mail-forwarding, exchangeonline

I have 2 distribution groups set up listening on 2 different email addresses:
`email@domain1.com` and `email@domain2.com`. I have one (Shared, if it makes a difference) mailbox set up `Emails`. This mailbox is configured to forward emails to an external address through the Exchange Admin Centre: `emails@external.com`.

If someone sends an email to `email@domain1.com` and CCs `email@domain2.com` then I my Exchange instance receives 2 copies of the email. The system appears to be smart enough to only keep one of the instances as far as the `Emails` mailbox is concerned, but the email gets forwarded to the external address twice.

Is there a way to configure this so that the email only gets forwarded once?

Comment: a mail comes and and gets out as addressed. it's just a simple command line that will be put on a server, aslong as you don't have a filter module or similar, it will send 2 or more times

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Even if you are setting up mail flow rules, there is no action to delete duplicate messages.